# Deleting all the items from a large list in SharePoint

Tags: list

What is the most efficient way to delete all the items of a large list in SharePoint?
The code should take Query throttling limits into consideration.

Comment: If you want to delete all the items in the list, delete the list and create a new list with same name.

Comment: That does not work if the list has workflows attached.

Answer (score 55):

The most efficient way to a lot of transaction in SharePoint is using of [SPWeb.ProcessBatchData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.processbatchdata.aspx) method. For deleting operations there are [very helpfull post](http://victorshi.com/blog/post/How-to-do-bulk-deletion-in-SharePoint). Code exaple from that post:

```
    // We prepare a String.Format with a String.Format, this is why we have a {{0}} 
   string command = String.Format("<Method><SetList Scope=\"Request\">{0}</SetList><SetVar Name=\"ID\">{{0}}</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"owsfileref\">{{1}}</SetVar></Method>", list.ID);
   // We get everything but we limit the result to 100 rows 
   SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
   q.RowLimit = 100;

   // While there's something left 
   while (list.ItemCount > 0)
   {
    // We get the results 
    SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems(q);

    StringBuilder sbDelete = new StringBuilder();
    sbDelete.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Batch>");

    Guid[] ids = new Guid[coll.Count];
    for (int i=0;i<coll.Count;i++)
    {
     SPListItem item = coll[i];
     sbDelete.Append(string.Format(command, item.ID.ToString(), item.File.ServerRelativeUrl));
     ids[i] = item.UniqueId;
    }
    sbDelete.Append("</Batch>");

    // We execute it 
    web.ProcessBatchData(sbDelete.ToString());

    //We remove items from recyclebin
    web.RecycleBin.Delete(ids);

    list.Update();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Cannot resist mentioning, that this will move items to recycle bin instead of actually deleting them.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Nice catch.

Comment: Thanks for remark! I updated code with batch deleting items from recycle bin.

Comment: @IAfanasov I'm curious how many items were in your list when you benchmarked this.

Comment: @Tom Resing we used this method in same scenario: list contains thousands items (in production it can grow to dozens of thousands) and per one operation we needed to delete hundreds items. We didn't measure perfomance, but it noticeably increased.

Comment: thanks IAfanasov, but I get an error when I call : web.RecycleBin.Delete(ids);
I store all the ListItem Unique GUID's in the GUID array, but still get the below mentioned error, any ideas: Delete failed, Error Message: Value does not fall within the expected range. Error Stack Trace: at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetSort
edIds(Guid[] ids) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.Delete(Guid[] ids) at CleanupWorkflowHistory.Program.PurgeHistoryList(String pSiteUrl, String pW
ebUrl, String pListName, Int32 pNumDays, UInt32 pMaxHistoryListDelete, Boolean p
ReportOnl

Comment: @IAfanasov - user8217 is right, there is a problem here. You delete the items from the recycle bin based on their old ID, but after they were deleted they get a new ID, so the code fails.

Answer (score 33):

I took a stab at converting IAfanasov's answer into PowerShell. Seems to work for me, but would be interested in any feedback.

```coffee
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

write-host 

# Enter your configuration here
$siteUrl = "http://mysharepointsite.example.com/"
$listName = "Name of my list"
$batchSize = 1000

write-host "Opening web at $siteUrl..."

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
write-host "Web is: $($web.Title)"

$list = $web.Lists[$listName];
write-host "List is: $($list.Title)"

while ($list.ItemCount -gt 0)
{
  write-host "Item count: $($list.ItemCount)"

  $batch = "<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"UTF-8`"?><Batch>"
  $i = 0

  foreach ($item in $list.Items)
  {
    $i++
    write-host "`rProcessing ID: $($item.ID) ($i of $batchSize)" -nonewline

    $batch += "<Method><SetList Scope=`"Request`">$($list.ID)</SetList><SetVar Name=`"ID`">$($item.ID)</SetVar><SetVar Name=`"Cmd`">Delete</SetVar><SetVar Name=`"owsfileref`">$($item.File.ServerRelativeUrl)</SetVar></Method>"

    if ($i -ge $batchSize) { break }
  }

  $batch += "</Batch>"

  write-host

  write-host "Sending batch..."

  # We execute it 
  $result = $web.ProcessBatchData($batch)

  write-host "Emptying Recycle Bin..."

  # We remove items from recyclebin
  $web.RecycleBin.DeleteAll()

  write-host

  $list.Update()
}

write-host "Done."
```

Comment: Very Helpful and instructive

Comment: This only works if you want to delete ALL items correct? What if we only want to delete all items in a particular view, or based on a criteria such as Title? I'm still pretty intermediate with PowerShell, if that; esp. WRT SharePoint.

Answer (score 25):

I like IAfanasov's response. `ProcesBatchData` is the way to go.

But you are asking about the *"most efficient way to delete **all** the items of a large list"*.  The most efficient way is to **delete the list and re-create it**, if you really want to delete all items. It will be a lot quicker than doing any iterative actions.

Comment: This approach is definitely acceptable in some cases, but you should take into account, that the lookup fields, which point to the deleted list, will be broken. Also, all the list views will be removed from all pages and from all sites.

Comment: Would it help to save the list as a template and NOT include the content? That should save the columns and views and permissions and so on...

Comment: @AlexPoint & omlin both correct. Saving the list as a template *should* take care of columns, views, permissions etc. - but sometimes it doesn't work, so I would first try it out before deleting the old list completely.

Comment: I came here to suggest the template option without content. That seems like it's at least worth a shot before running some code.

Comment: @DennisG: Saving a list as a list template does not include permissions. Exporting the list via Export-SPWeb -IncludeUserSecurity (you can restrict the export to your list via -ItemUrl "lists/YourList") "preserves the user security settings except for SPLists that have broken inheritance and item level permissions set", but the list will be re-created using a new ID, so lookup fields referencing the list will be still broken.

Comment: If you have workflows which are dependent on fields of this list, then they will be broken and must be recreated.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to IAfanosov's solution, I've written a method to clear the recycle bin from all items that were deleted from the given list:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes all items from the recycle bin in a web that originally came from the given list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceList">List where the items originated from</param>
private static void TruncateRecycleBin(SPList sourceList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Truncating recycle bin of all items deleted from list [{0}]", sourceList.Title);

    SPRecycleBinItemCollection recycleBin = sourceList.ParentWeb.RecycleBin;
    List<Guid> itemsToDelete = new List<Guid>();
    for (int i = 0; i < recycleBin.Count; i++)
    {
        // Only delete items from this specific list
        if (recycleBin[i].DirName.StartsWith(sourceList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString()))
        {
            itemsToDelete.Add(recycleBin[i].ID);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("About to delete [{0}] items from recycle bin...", itemsToDelete.Count);
    if (itemsToDelete.Count > 0)
    {
        recycleBin.Delete(itemsToDelete.ToArray());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done truncating recycle bin.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that works great! Just 1 glitch. You will have to replace if (recycleBin[i].DirName.StartsWith(sourceList.RootFolder.ToString())) with if(recycleBin[i].DirName.StartsWith(sourceList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.Substring(1))) for it to work on a list in a subsite.

Answer (score 7):

Navigate to DATA SHEET VIEW  (List tools > List > data sheet view)

Just select & delete all the rows in the sheet and move back to STANDARD VIEW.

Does this sounds like an effective way using UI ?

Comment: For thousands of list items? No. For 10s of thousands of lists items? Definitely not.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but...

Easiest way for me is to open in access view,

- Select "Link to data on the SharePoint site"
- Select all items and "Delete"
- Save changes to SharePoint site

DONE :)

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell is the way to go.  The following will parse 500 items at a time into the recycle bin and then remove them from the recycle bin.  I've used this on lists up to 700k items.

```
# Enter your configuration here
$siteUrl = "http://sitecollectionurl"
$listName = "Name of List"
$batchSize = 500

write-host "Opening web at $siteUrl..."

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
write-host "Web is: $($web.Title)"

$list = $web.Lists[$listName];
write-host "List is: $($list.Title)"

while ($list.ItemCount -gt 0)
{
  write-host "Item count: $($list.ItemCount)"

  $batch = "<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"UTF-8`"?><Batch>"
  $i = 0

  foreach ($item in $list.Items)
  {
    $i++
    write-host "`rProcessing ID: $($item.ID) ($i of $batchSize)" -nonewline

    $batch += "<Method><SetList Scope=`"Request`">$($list.ID)</SetList><SetVar Name=`"ID`">$($item.ID)</SetVar><SetVar Name=`"Cmd`">Delete</SetVar><SetVar Name=`"owsfileref`">$($item.File.ServerRelativeUrl)</SetVar></Method>"

    if ($i -ge $batchSize) { break }
  }

  $batch += "</Batch>"

  write-host

  write-host "Sending batch..."

  # We execute it 
  $result = $web.ProcessBatchData($batch)

  write-host "Emptying Recycle Bin..."

  # We remove items from recyclebin
  $web.RecycleBin.DeleteAll()

  write-host

  $list.Update()
}

write-host "Done."
```

I did see some formatting errors when copying into the forum but the script is solid.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Check and add SharePoint PowerShell snap-in
if(-not(
Get-PSSnapin | Where { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"})
) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}
$SITEURL = "http://sitename"

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite ( $SITEURL )
$web = $site.OpenWeb()

$oList = $web.Lists["Catering Consumption"];

$collListItems = $oList.Items;
$count = $collListItems.Count - 1

for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--)
{
    $collListItems.Delete($intIndex);
}
```

above method might be slow in bigger lists, to delete bigger lists faster, you can go for below method

```
Get-SPWeb $FooUrl | % { $_.Lists.Delete([System.Guid]$_.Lists["Catering Consumption"].ID) }
```

Please note in above example list name is  : Catering Consumption

Answer (score 2):

What about linking to the list in Access, then doing a SQL query: `DELETE * FROM [MyTable]` ?

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is create a datasheet view with no filter, select all rows, and hit the delete button.

Comment: How well does that work when you are dealing with large lists? Lets say 50K+ items.  Good luck

Comment: I don't know. I think as long as the list displays in datasheet view, it would work. However, I would expect it to take a long time and to cause database locks during that time.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You can use this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPSite site = new SPSite([Sharepoint Server]);
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPList list = web.Lists[List Name];

    deleteAllRerecords(list);
    web.Update();

}

public void deleteAllRerecords(SPList list)
{
    SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
    for (int i = items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        items[i].Delete();
    }

}
```