# Delete all survey responses

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, survey-list

Hopefully a simple question yet I can't seem to find a simple answer.  In SharePoint 2010 Foundation, how can I delete ALL survey responses at once?  I can delete one at a time, but with over 450 responses, that will not do.

We have a periodic survey that we need to clear so we can open it up again to see if there have been any improvements in our scores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open ***site manager*** by adding *_layouts/sitemanager.aspx* in the
  url.  (e.g) http://www.servername:10001/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx
- You can access the same in Site Actions >> Manage Content and
  Structure ( in SP 2007) (or) Site Settings>> Site Administration>>
  Content and Structure (in SP 2010).
- Navigate down to your survey.
- Select all responses and go to Actions >> delete.

Alternatively, you can find a useful [link](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2010/06/how-to-remove-all-responses-from-sharepoint-survey.html#ixzz2aWEVFujy) here

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had found that information prior but when I go to the sitemanager.aspx page, I get an `Unexpected Error` and there is no `Content and Structure` option in `Site Settings -> Site Admin`.  I had wondered if using this was a feature missing in Foundation.

Comment: Can you perform the following steps:
Navigate to _Site Settings_, click _Modify All Site Settings_, and then under _Site Collection Administration_, click _Go to top level site settings_.
Under _Site Administration_, click _Content and Structure_.

Note: To access the Site Content and Structure page, you must have a minimum of Contribute permissions.

Answer (score 2):

While there are ways to delete all items from a [list](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c789508f-891d-43de-8b1a-85d7c1d67d60/one-line-powershell-to-delete-all-list-items?forum=sharepointadminprevious) (e.g. through [powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/how-to-delete-all-items-in-alist-using-powershell) on the sharepoint server) (I would advise testing this code on another list or dev environment first to make sure you understand what it is doing):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite
$list = $web.Lists["My Survey"]

while($list.Items.Count -gt 0){$list.Items.Delete(0)}
```

Another simple option is to save the list as a [list template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-list-by-using-a-list-template-HA101782479.aspx) (without the content), then create a new survey list from the site template:

Click List Settings -> Save List as Template. 
Make sure "Include Content" is unchecked.
Click OK.
Go to Site Actions -> Create List.  Find the list template you created and click OK. Give it a new name (e.g. People survey 2013).
Now you have a copied empty survey list with the original data in tact as well. :)

Comment: I have assumed a relatively small/medium sized list for the deletion code. If you have a large list, you may be better of using a batch deletion command to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to Remove All Responses from SharePoint Survey is: using "Site Content and Structure Manager".

1. Go to Site Actions > **Site Content and Structure Manager**'
2. you can click the **header Double check-box Icon** to select all items
3. Now select actions -> **delete**

Find the detailed example at: [How to Remove All Responses from SharePoint Survey](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2010/06/how-to-remove-all-responses-from-sharepoint-survey.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Content & Structure in SP2010.. Save as a template and start over?  All these answers are bogus.

Comment: You are correct - Content and Structure are "missing" in SP 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Save the survey as a template in the list settings (do not include content)
Create a new empty copy of the survey from that template(delete the old one first if you want the same name)

I love how everyone always assumes people have enterprise features (the sitemanager) or want code when simple options are available.