# Fastest way to delete thousands of listitems

Tags: 2010

I have a list with about 500.000 thousand items.
I need to delete all list items which created date is after a specific date.

The query would match about 450.000 thousand items. And then delete all of them.

Whats the fastest way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/deleting-all-the-items-from-a-large-list-in-sharepoint
and
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39579/fastest-way-to-delete-all-items-with-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do batch deletes using SPWeb.ProcessBatchData method.

Answer (score 1):

Here Is good code for this:

```
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;


        SPList list = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"];
        StringBuilder sbDelete = BuildBatchDeleteCommand(list);
        witryna.ProcessBatchData(sbDelete.ToString());
    }

    private static StringBuilder BuildBatchDeleteCommand(SPList spList)
    {

        StringBuilder sbDelete = new StringBuilder();

        sbDelete.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Batch>");

        string command = "<Method><SetList Scope=\"Request\">" + spList.ID +

        "</SetList><SetVar Name=\"ID\">{0}</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar></Method>";


        foreach (SPListItem item in spList.Items)
        {

            sbDelete.Append(string.Format(command, item.ID.ToString()));

        }

        sbDelete.Append("</Batch>");

        return sbDelete;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be connecting to the list via Access and running a delete query against the list.

Comment: ThisI think would be the quickest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small jQuery-snippet with SPServices, [This forum post](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/245147) seems to work, so just change the listname and the CAML Query according to your criteria.

Comment: But how we can use this on cs files ?