# Delete list records

Tags: list, delete

I need to delete all records in sharepoint list. Is there any way to do this in low time? I tried using powershell but it takes more time. My list may contain more than 50000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suren,

This question seems a possible duplicate of following question:
[Deleting all the items from a large list in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/deleting-all-the-items-from-a-large-list-in-sharepoint)

Please view the answers there and use the one feasible in your case!