# How to delete a view that is over the list-view threshold?

Tags: list-view-threshold

I created a view that will not display because it contains over 5000 entries. Now I cannot edit it or delete it.

Anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: Office 365 or on-prem?

Comment: How many items approx return in that view?

Answer (score 1):

One thing, if you using the on prem version of SharePoint then an easy solution is

- increase the List view threshold to above the number of items in that view
- delete the view
- reset the threshold back to normal.

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-list-view-threshold.html

For Office 365, check [Office 365/SharePoint Online – Getting Around the List View Threshold Error](http://www.andrewjbillings.com/office-365sharepoint-online-getting-around-the-list-view-threshold-error/)

Comment: Thanks. We are using Office 365. I will try this solution and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to fix the issue without deleting View.

First try to remember if the View is a filtered view. If it is not filtered then we have not choice rather delete the view.

Now open the list settings and - Open Indexed columns and add the columns which you used in the Filter criteria.

Next try opening the view and it will work as expected.

**Removing View using PowerShell**

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://weburl
$List = $SPWeb.Lists["ListName"]
$View = $List.Views["ViewName"]
$List.Views.Delete($View.ID)
$List.Update()
$SPWeb.Update()
$SPWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: i highly doubt whether this will work or not because untill the threshold of the list is changed it may not allow even with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a trick from [HNR949](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/173929/60299)

His solution was to open the large list in MICROSOFT ACCESS and delete some or all Items from the List.

When your List is again below Threshold then you are free to do what you like with your List.