# SP - Delete list item and folders in Recycle bin with C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem, delete, recycle-bin

I'm with SP13 On-prem and I want to delete all items from lists and all folder in doclibraries in recycle bin...

**This is my code for list:**

```
if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList)
{
      while (list.Items.Count > 0)
      {
          list.Items[0].Recycle();
      }
}
```

> **Error message:** Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not
>   execute. **Error stackTrace:** at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.SPEnumerator.System
>   .Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()
>
> And.....items not moving in recycle

**This is code for doclib:**

```
    if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
    {
          string libURL = oWeb.Url + "/" + list.RootFolder.Url;
          SPFolderCollection folders = oWeb.Folders[libURL].SubFolders;
          foreach (SPFolder folder in folders)
          {
              if (!folder.Name.Contains("Forms"))
              {
                 oWeb.Folders[libURL].SubFolders.Delete(folder.Url).Recyclebin();
              }
          }
}
```

How to delete folder in Recycle ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send items to Recycle bin, you can do like this:

```
//Custom List
if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList)
{
    SPListItemCollection coll = list.Items;

    foreach (SPListItem listitem in coll)
    {
        SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listitem.ID);
        itemToDelete.Recycle();
    }
}

// Document Library
if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
{
    string libURL = oWeb.Url + "/" + list.RootFolder.Url;
    SPFolderCollection folders = oWeb.Folders[libURL].SubFolders;

    foreach (SPFolder folder in folders)
    {
        if (!folder.Name.Contains("Forms"))
        {
            SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(folder.Item.ID);
            itemToDelete.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
[Your code](http://textuploader.com/ddp1m) also fails on:

```
foreach (SPList list in fundListsAndLibs)
```

So I adapted [your code](http://textuploader.com/ddp1m), getting lists Title and then retrieving each list by Title, making no difference between lists and libraries and extracting firstly items and then only first level folders.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
{
    try
    {
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(fundURL))
        {
            using (var oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                // Get lists Title
                var fundListsAndLibs = (from SPList list in oWeb.Lists select list.Title);

                // To Skip Titles
                var skipLibs = new[] { "DataAccessLib", "Pages" };

                // Extract desidered Lists Title
                var desideredLists = fundListsAndLibs.Where(l => !skipLibs.Contains(l)).ToList();


                foreach (string listName in desideredLists)
                {
                    // Try get list
                    var list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (list == null) continue;

                    // Retrieve only items
                    var queryItems = new SPQuery();
                    queryItems.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'></View>";
                    var items = list.GetItems(queryItems);
                    foreach (SPListItem listitem in items)
                    {
                        SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listitem.ID);
                        itemToDelete.Recycle();
                    }

                    // Retrieve only first level folders
                    var query = new SPQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = string.Format(@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                                        <Query>
                                                            <Where>
                                                            <And>
                                                                <Eq>
                                                                    <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                                                                    <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
                                                                </Eq>
                                                                <Eq>
                                                                    <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/>
                                                                    <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                                                </Eq>
                                                            </And>
                                                            </Where>
                                                        </Query>
                                                    </View>"
                                                    , list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    var folders = list.GetItems(query);
                    foreach (SPListItem listitem in folders)
                    {
                        SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listitem.ID);
                        itemToDelete.Recycle();
                    }
                }

                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message + " Error stackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
});
```

Comment: With this code i have this error: Error message: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. E
rror stackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.SPEnumerator.System
.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()

Comment: And the items doesnt go to the Recycle bin...

Comment: I tested the code and it's working. Can you please attach the entire code you are using?

Comment: Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Take a look on the updated answer. I adapted your code.

Comment: Everything is good, no exception, but items doesnt go to the Recycle bin

Comment: Items are still in lists/document libraries or not? Consider that running code with Elevated Privileges sends items to the Site Collection Recycle bin (_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx) and not to the webs Recycle bin (_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For sharepoint list, use below code:

```
if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList)
{
    if (list != null)
    {
        int itemCount = list.ItemCount;
        for (int k=0; k<itemCount; k++)
        {
            listItems[k].Recycle();

        }   
    }   
}
```

Or use the Batchcommand to delete all list items as below:

```
public static void DeleteAllItems(string site, string list)
{
    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(site))
    {
        using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            StringBuilder deletebuilder = BatchCommand(spWeb.Lists[list]);
            spSite.RootWeb.ProcessBatchData(deletebuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private static StringBuilder BatchCommand(SPList spList)
{
    StringBuilder deletebuilder= new StringBuilder();
    deletebuilder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Batch>");
    string command = "<Method><SetList Scope=\"Request\">" + spList.ID +
        "</SetList><SetVar Name=\"ID\">{0}</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"owsfileref\">{1}</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar></Method>";

    foreach (SPListItem item in spList.Items)
    {
        deletebuilder.Append(string.Format(command, item.ID.ToString(),item["FileRef"].ToString()));
    }
    deletebuilder.Append("</Batch>");
    return deletebuilder;
}
```

reference - [Deleting all the items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/deleting-all-the-items-from-a-large-list-in-sharepoint)

```
// We prepare a String.Format with a String.Format, this is why we have a {{0}} 
string command = String.Format("<Method><SetList Scope=\"Request\">{0}</SetList><SetVar Name=\"ID\">{{0}}</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"owsfileref\">{{1}}</SetVar></Method>", list.ID);
// We get everything but we limit the result to 100 rows 
SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
q.RowLimit = 100;

// While there's something left 
    while (list.ItemCount > 0)
    {
        // We get the results 
        SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems(q);

        StringBuilder sbDelete = new StringBuilder();
        sbDelete.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Batch>");

        Guid[] ids = new Guid[coll.Count];
        for (int i=0;i<coll.Count;i++)
        {
         SPListItem item = coll[i];
         sbDelete.Append(string.Format(command, item.ID.ToString(), item.File.ServerRelativeUrl));
         ids[i] = item.UniqueId;
        }
        sbDelete.Append("</Batch>");

        // We execute it 
        web.ProcessBatchData(sbDelete.ToString());

        list.Update();
    }
```

[Deleting all the items from a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/deleting-all-the-items-from-a-large-list-in-sharepoint)

Comment: with first code error is: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. E rror stackTrace: at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.SPEnumerator.System .Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()

Comment: Item is deleted, but not go to Recycle bin... and throw above exception

Comment: Check updated code.